# Unable to select value from drop downlist .Tried all possibilties but no luck

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is my code trials,

```
package com.qa.pages;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindAll;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import com.qa.base.TestBase;
import com.qa.commonutils.CommonUtils;


public class Loginpage extends TestBase {

    //Page factory(OR)
    //tooltip of abhibus image xpath
    @FindBy(xpath="//div//a//img[contains(@title,\"abhibus.com - India's Fastest Online bus ticket booking site\")]")
    static WebElement titletooltip;

    //id for leaving from field
    @FindBy(id="source")
    static WebElement leavingfrom;

    //id for going to  field
    @FindBy(id="destination")
    static WebElement goingto;

    //id for date picker for date of journey
    @FindBy(id="datepicker1")
    static WebElement dateofjourney;

    //id for date picker for date of return
    @FindBy(id="datepicker2")
    static WebElement dateofreturn;

    //Click on search button
    @FindBy(xpath="//div[@id='roundTrip']//a[contains(@title,'Search Buses')]")
    static WebElement searchbutton;

    @FindAll( {@FindBy(xpath = "//li[@class='ui-menu-item']//parent::li")} )
    static List<WebElement>listofdropdownleaving;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//li[@class='ui-menu-item']//parent::li")
    static WebElement leavingdropdownpath;

    @FindAll( {@FindBy(xpath = "//li[@class='ui-menu-item']//parent::ul//following::ul//li")} )
    static List<WebElement>listofdropdowngoingto;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//li[@class='ui-menu-item']//parent::ul//following::ul//li")
    static WebElement leavingdropdowngoingto;

    @FindAll( {@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='col2']//span//parent::a")} )
    static List<WebElement> selectseatbtn;

    @FindAll( {@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id='seatSelect1']//li[@class='sleeper available']//parent::a")} )
    static List<WebElement> selectionofseats;

    @FindBy(xpath="//a[@id='O7-2ZZ']")
    static WebElement selectseat;

    @FindBy(xpath="//span[@id='totalfare']")
    static WebElement totalamount;

    @FindBy(xpath="//select[@id='boardingpoint_id1']")
    static WebElement boardingpoint;

    @FindAll( {@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='clearfix']//select[@id='boardingpoint_id1']")} )
    static List<WebElement>listofdropdownvalue;

    @FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='red-landmark']")
    static WebElement boardingpointaddress;




public Loginpage() {

    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}


public static void verifysearchbusfun() {
    leavingfrom.sendKeys(Prop.getProperty("leavingfrom"));
    tempExplicityWait(listofdropdownleaving,"Hyderabad Airport",leavingdropdownpath);
    goingto.sendKeys(Prop.getProperty("goingto"));
    tempExplicityWait(listofdropdowngoingto,"Bangalore",leavingdropdowngoingto);
    String dateval=Prop.getProperty("dateval");
    selectDateByJs(driver,dateofjourney,dateval);
    String dateofreturnfromconfig=Prop.getProperty("dateofreturn");
    selectDateByJs(driver,dateofreturn,dateofreturnfromconfig);
    searchbutton.click();

}
```

//Got the values and tried in below way also no luck.

```
public static void tempdrop() {
    List<WebElement>dd = driver.findElements(By.tagName("select"));
    System.out.println("Size of the dropdownvalue" +dd.size());
    for(int i=0;i<dd.size();i++)
    {
        String value =dd.get(i).getText();
        System.out.println("values are from dropdownlist " +value);
        String[] words=value.split("\\s");//splits the string based on whitespace    
        for(String w:words){  
        System.out.println("Splitted words value  "+w);  
        if(w.equalsIgnoreCase("Shamshabad-22:10"))
        {
        Select ddvalue= new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("//div//select[@id='boardingpoint_id1']//parent::select//preceding::select")));
        ddvalue.selectByVisibleText(w);
        break;
        }
        }  
    }
    }

    public static void drop() {
        ExplicityWaitmethod(driver.findElement(By.id("//div//select[@id='boardingpoint_id1']//parent::select//preceding::select")));
        Select ddvalue= new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("//div//select[@id='boardingpoint_id1']//parent::select//preceding::select")));
        //ddvalue.selectByIndex(1);
        ddvalue.selectByVisibleText("Shamshabad-22:10");

    //listofdropdownvalue.size();
    //System.out.println("Size of dropdownvalue :" +listofdropdownvalue.size());
}

public static String gettooltip()
{
    actions(titletooltip);
    return titletooltip.getAttribute("title");
}

public static void actions(WebElement pathelement) {

        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        act.moveToElement(pathelement).build().perform();
    }

public static void selectDateByJs(WebDriver driver,WebElement element,String dateval)
{
    JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver);
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','"+dateval+"');",element);

}
public static void ExplicityWaitmethod(WebElement element) {

    try {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions
            .visibilityOf((element)));
        }
catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }
}



public static void selectseatbtn(List<WebElement> list) {

    //**************Clicked on select seat button
            try {
            list.size();
            System.out.println("Size of the seats available in the page " +list.size());
            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
            {
                boolean value =list.get(i).isEnabled();
                if(value==true)
                {
                    list.get(i).click();
                    break;
                }
            }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
              System.out.println("Seats are not available");
            }
}

public static void selectionofseats(List<WebElement> list)
{
    //***********Seat selection
            try
            {
                list.size();
            System.out.println("Available seats in the page  " +list.size());
            for(int j=0;j<list.size();j++)
            {
                boolean seatavailabilty =list.get(j).isEnabled();
                if(seatavailabilty==true)
                {
                    list.get(j).click();
                    break;
                }   
            }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.getMessage();
            }       
}
public static void selectseats() {
    selectseatbtn(selectseatbtn);
    selectionofseats(selectionofseats);
    javascriptexecutor();
    drop();
    //tempdrop();
    //dropdownvalue();
    //gettextfromfield(totalamount);
    //gettextfromfield(boardingpointaddress);

    //selectdropdown();

    /*Select boardingvalue = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("boardingpoint_id1")));
    boardingvalue.selectByVisibleText("Shamshabad-21:15");
*/


}

public static String gettextfromfield(WebElement element) {
    System.out.println("Value got from the field  "+totalamount.getText());
    return totalamount.getText();

}
public static void javascriptexecutor() {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)(driver);
    js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");

}
```

//Tried by using javascript executor and scroll down and selected values .but no luck

```
public static void dropdownvalue() {
        try
        {
            javascriptexecutor();
            //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
                    //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id("boardingpoint_id1"))));
            Select ddvalue= new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div//select[@id='boardingpoint_id1']//option[text()='Shamshabad-21:15']")));
            boolean value=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div//select[@id='boardingpoint_id1']//option[text()='Shamshabad-21:15']")).isSelected();
            if(value==true)
            {
                WebElement optionvalue =ddvalue.getFirstSelectedOption();
                System.out.println(optionvalue.getAttribute("value"));
                System.out.println(optionvalue.getText());
                ddvalue.selectByIndex(1);
                ddvalue.selectByVisibleText("Shamshabad-21:15");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("dropdownvalue is not selected");
            e.getMessage();
        }

        }
    public static void tempExplicityWait(List<WebElement> list,String Name,WebElement xpath) {

        try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                .visibilityOf(xpath));
        list.size();
        System.out.println("Auto Suggest List ::" + list.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Value got from the loop   " +list.get(i).getText());

            if (list.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase(Name)) {
                System.out.println("Selected Value from list " +list.get(i).getText());
                list.get(i).click();
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
    }
    }
```

I have tried all possibilities by creating method for dropdownlist. Same thing is working with sample code(hard coded values). Please guide me where I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: please attach the HTML code so we can help you debugging it

Comment: @AutomatedOwl url is  _https://www.abhibus.com/_

Comment: <select class="dropdown_custom" name="boardingpoint_id1" id="boardingpoint_id1" onchange="insertText(this.value,'321','5','GOTOUR - 004 (E-CITY)','499715996');" style="width:160px ! important;">
     <option value="">Boarding Point </option>
     <option value="68351^Shamshabad^09:15 PM^O R R Exit No 16 Toll Gate, Towards Bangalore, Opp Jama Masjid Thondpally^04023813113 9483071100^O R R Exit No 16 Toll Gate, Towards Bangalore, Opp Jama Masjid Thondpally">Shamshabad-21:15</option>     </select>

Comment: List<WebElement>dd = driver.findElements(By.tagName("select"));
 System.out.println("Size of the dropdownvalue" +dd.size());
 for(int i=0;i<dd.size();i++)
 {
  String value =dd.get(i).getText();
  System.out.println("values are from dropdownlist " +value);
  String[] words=value.split("\\W+");//splits the string based on whitespace

Comment: for(String w:words)
  {  
  System.out.println("Splitted words value  "+w); 
  if(w.equalsIgnoreCase("Shamshabad-22:10"))
  {
  Select ddvalue= new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div//select[@id='boardingpoint_id1']//parent::select//preceding::select")));
  ddvalue.selectByVisibleText(w);
  break;
  }
  }  
 }
 }

Comment: Got the select values by using list of element  and i used for loop ,i got the values and everythng and in if condition while debugging not going inside the loop wven condition is true.can you please help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Got the solution.Thanks:)

public static void tempdrop() {
    Select oSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.tagName("select")));
    List <WebElement> elementCount = oSelect.getOptions();
    System.out.println(elementCount.size());
    for(int i =0; i<elementCount.size() ; i++){
        String sValue = elementCount.get(i).getText();
        System.out.println(sValue);
        }
    oSelect.selectByVisibleText("Shamshabad-21:15");
    }
```